# How can I create log file with spider name in settings.py dynamically?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-settings

I have 20 different spiders and it works scheduled. End of the day, when I check the log file I am getting over 15.000 line log.

***My recent log setting in settings.py***

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today()
now_time = now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")

LOG_FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
LOG_FILE = 'scrapy-log-'+now_time+'.txt'
```

But I want to prepare log file depends on spider name like

***What I expect in settings.py***

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today()
now_time = now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")

LOG_FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
LOG_FILE = spider_name+now_time+'.txt'
```

But I don't know how to get spider_name dynamically when crawling all spiders.

So the question is how can I use spider_name dynamically in settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding settings upon instantiating the spider. Something like this:

```
class YourSpider(CrawlSpider):

    start_urls = ['http://website.com']
    allowed_domains = ['www.website.com']

    name = 'spider_name'
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_FILE' = name+now_time+'.txt',
    }
```

See section "2. Settings per-spider" in documentation https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: Now time is not working dynamically I try to add in init it doesn't work also I try the @property function it doesn't work too.

Comment: It should work the same as spider_name as long as you import your datetime module in the spider module and create the variable now_time in your spider class

Comment: I see but when I run script the class start with today’s date and it stays same

Comment: Anyway your way helps alot. I will open another question for that.

Comment: Ok, I understood why. Its because the spier gets instantiated only once so only the time from that instantiation is saved. You could use the logging function within parse_item or maybe pipeliens to get the current time and also to write your logs with the current spider_name. Its explained in "Logging from Spiders"  section in docs https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html
Hope it helps